# Subset sum but even subset size

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

So, basically it's the same idea as the subset sum problem, but with one restriction: The **found subset needs to have an even size**.

For example:

```
numbers {4, 3, 3, 5, 1, 2, 7, 12}
find subset that sums up to 10
=> solution: {4, 3, 1, 2} (or {3, 7} but not {4, 3, 3} )
```

Is there a simple method to find such a subset? (The method should be "efficient", not just trying all possible subsets...)

Here is my code to find a "normal" subset:

```
    int n = 8;
    int m = 11;
    boolean[][] S = new boolean[n][m];
    int[] N = new int[] {4, 3, 3, 5, 1, 2, 7, 12};
    S[0][0] = true;
    S[0][S[0]] = true;

for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if(N[i] == j) {
                S[i][j] = true;
            } else if(j - N[i] >= 0) {
                S[i][j] = S[i-1][j] || S[i-1][j - N[i]];
            } else {
                S[i][j] = S[i-1][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't you find all possible subsets and then filter even-sized ones?

Comment: Do you need to find all subsets of an even size, or just one?

Comment: @JacobG. I know I could just do that but that's not really efficient, isn't it? Because I'm using large inputs.
I just need to find one...

Comment: @JacobG. I think it would be more efficient to find all even-sized subsets and then determine the subsets thats sum equals the correct value

Comment: @PrestonM how can I find an even sized subset? I know how I can find normal ones, but just even ones?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have now?

Comment: @PrestonM To find a normal subset, I'm just using the normal subset sum algorithm. (I haven't inculded the backtracking of the solution yet)

Comment: So, you want to we do your homework?

Comment: @Luisk4 first: nobody said that this is homework exercise (it actually isn't), secondly: nobody said you should give me a solution to this, thirdly: why don't you just help and give me hint how to solve it? (assuming you know how to do it)

Answer (score 0):

In your current code S[i][j] is true if you can make value j as a subset of numbers up to i.

Instead, compute S[i][j][k] is true if you can make value j as a subset of numbers up to i with the number of numbers used equal to k modulo 2.

In other words, k is either 0 or 1.

This will require around twice the computations of your existing solution.

Comment: hmm... I don't quite understand. In what range is k? Because if it would be in range {0, 1}, the amount of numbers used could then only be 0 or 1?? Or is k in range {0, 1, ..., N.length}? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: k is in range{0,1}.  k==0 is used to count subsets with an even number of elements, k==1 is used for subsets with an odd number of elements.